# .animate() not working more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I wrote the following code that includes a *"down arrow"*  which when pressed, is meant to scroll the page down one section at a time. It only seems to work once though - can anyone see what I've done wrong?

***Note:*** *The body height intentional and is enough to support my needs.*

```
<STYLE>
*{margin:0;padding:0}
body{height:1000px; width:2000px; overflow:hidden;}
SECTION{border: 1px dashed black; height:100px; width:300px; overflow:auto; float:top;}
.int{position:relative; width:100px;height:100px;background:#fff; float:left;}
</STYLE>

<SECTION ID="1">1</SECTION>
<SECTION ID="2">2</SECTION>
<SECTION ID="3">3</SECTION>

<SCRIPT SRC="jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>

function scroll($dir){
    // This is the main scroll function
    if($dir=="down")
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $('html,body').offset().top + $("SECTION#1").height()
        }, 800, "easeInQuart");
}

// Function which controls key-based navigation
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.which == 40) scroll("down");
});

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

`$('html,body').offset().top + $("SECTION#1").height()` always returns the same value. So that is why it is not working.

As a solution, try `$(document).offset().top` or use a counter like so:

```
var currentPage = 0;
function scrollDown() {
    $(...).animate({scrollTop: pageHeight * (currentPage++)});
}
```